# POST request blocked by CORS policy from local Angular application but works fine in Postman and Thunder Client

Tags: angular, cors, xmlhttprequest, http-headers

I'm developing a web app that requests a list of jobs from an api on a remote server, in the form of json, so I can insert them in a mat-table.

the company sent me a link to the list of API's that I need, along with a template that I can try requests with it. For clarification, it looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01kAa.png).

the POST request works like a charm on the template, with Postman and also Thunder Client (on VSCode).

- ***these are the response headers:***

```
 access-control-allow-credentials: * 
 access-control-allow-headers: content-type,server,strict-transport-security,x-powered-by,date 
 access-control-allow-methods: GET,HEAD,POST,PUT,DELETE,CONNECT,OPTIONS,TRACE,PATCH 
 access-control-allow-origin: * 
 access-control-expose-headers: * 
 content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8 
 date: Mon,04 Jul 2022 14:39:42 GMT 
 server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0 
 strict-transport-security: max-age=2592000 
 x-content-type-options: nosniff 
 x-powered-by: ASP.NET
```

However, it raises an error when performing the request from my Angular app, ***this is the error on Brave Browser Console:***

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at '(***API URL***)' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.
```

***This is the error on Mozilla Firefox Console:***

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://blmbwebapi.weker.fr/api/jobs/listJobs. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 405.

Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://blmbwebapi.weker.fr/api/jobs/listJobs. (Reason: CORS request did not succeed). Status code: (null).
```

my code looks like this:

***list-jobs.service.ts: (Snippet)**

```
export class ListJobsService {

  public baseUrl = "/* API URL */";

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  public getJobs(): Observable<any> { 

    let body = {"pageIndex": 0,
                "pageSize": 10,
                "filters": [ {"filterName": "csvFile", 
                              "filterValue": "flash-sales-export_20170217_080032.csv", 
                              "filterValues": [ "string" ] } ],
                "sortInfos": [ {"sortColumn": "string",
                                "sortOrdor": 0 } ] };


    let options = { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json') };
    return this.httpClient.post(this.baseUrl,body, options);
   }
```

***jobs.component.ts:(Snippet)***

```
ngOnInit(): void {

    this.listJobsService.getJobs().subscribe(data => {
      this.jobs = data;
      console.log(data);});
    
  }
```

If any further information is need, please tell me!

Thank you so much.

Comment: I should mention that i have allowed CORS in both Brave Browser and Mozilla Firefox, using two different extensions (Moesif CORS and CORS Everywhere, respectively), both are working fine.

Comment: CORS is something you enable, not on the client side, but on the server side.

Comment: What does authentication consist in with this API? A `Authorization: Bearer xxx` header?

Comment: @jub0bs the fact that CORS is already enabled on the server baffles me. Also the response header as I mentioned looks fine with : `  access-control-allow-origin: *  `

Comment: Their CORS seem misconfigured. Read the fine print: https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#cors-non-wildcard-request-header-name. A wildcard in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header doesn't apply to `Authorization`.

Comment: @jub0bs PROBLEM SOLVED, I worked around it with Angular CLI Proxy, and created a proxy.conf.json file in my root folder. I needed to fool my browser by by pretending to have the API on the same origin. there is no Bearer token or API Key needed for it. Thank for your help!

Comment: This proxy of yours is only a temporary measure. When you release your client to production, you'll have to deal with CORS properly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Problem Solved

I worked around it with Angular CLI Proxy, and created a **proxy.conf.json** file in my root folder. I needed to fool my browser by by pretending to have the API on the same origin. there is no Bearer token or API Key needed for it.

then I started my app with:

`ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json`

my proxy.conf.json file contains this:

```
{
    "/api": {
        "target": "(THE REAL API URL)",
        "secure": true,
        "changeOrigin": true,
        "pathRewrite": {
            "^/api": ""
        }
    }
}
```

- `/api` property of the object specifies the route for the proxy and
  the nested object specifies the configuration. So I changed my api
  url in the service method to `http://localhost:4200/api`.
- `pathRewrite` property allowed me modify how the application
  interacts with the target.

It became:

```
export class ListJobsService {

  public baseUrl = "http://localhost:4200/api";

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  public getJobs(): Observable<any> { 

    let body = {"pageIndex": 0,
                "pageSize": 10,
                "filters": [ {"filterName": "csvFile", 
                              "filterValue": "flash-sales-export_20170217_080032.csv", 
                              "filterValues": [ "string" ] } ],
                "sortInfos": [ {"sortColumn": "string",
                                "sortOrdor": 0 } ] };


    let options = { headers: new HttpHeaders().set('Content-Type', 'application/json') };
    return this.httpClient.post(this.baseUrl,body, options);
   }
```